# Package java desktop app (gradle)

Tags: java, gradle

According to this [oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/self-contained-packaging.html) there is a conventional java app packaging along with runtime JRE. (Self-Contained Application Packaging)

I know that there is this [thing (Launch4j gradle plugin)](https://github.com/TheBoegl/gradle-launch4j) but I'd prefer to have a bat/sh executables along in the package.

Going through gradle docs and googling I can not seem to find is there is a way to teach gradle to package desktop app with JRE. Is there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this plugin yet?

https://github.com/FibreFoX/javafx-gradle-plugin